# contentmd5 azure block/chunk download

Tags: azure, download, storage, block

So, I'm able to block/chunk upload a large file to Azure Storage via:

```
// upload blocks
blockBlob.PutBlock(blockId: blockID,
                   blockData: new MemoryStream(buffer),
                   contentMD5: blockHash,
                   accessCondition: null,
                   options: new BlobRequestOptions()
                   {
                      StoreBlobContentMD5 = true,
                      UseTransactionalMD5 = true
                   },
                   operationContext: null);

// set hash for the entire blob
blockBlob.Properties.ContentMD5 = fileHash;

// commit all uploaded blobs
blockBlob.PutBlockList(blockList: blockIDs,
                       accessCondition: null,
                       options: new BlobRequestOptions()
                       {
                          StoreBlobContentMD5 = true,
                          UseTransactionalMD5 = true
                       },
                       operationContext: null);
```

Now, I'm trying to download this large file in block/chunk again via:

```
// download blocks
blockBlob.DownloadRangeToByteArray(target: blobContents, 
                                   index: 0, 
                                   blobOffset: startPosition, 
                                   length: blobContents.Length, 
                                   accessCondition: null, 
                                   options: new BlobRequestOptions()
                                   {
                                      UseTransactionalMD5 = true
                                   }, 
                                   operationContext: null);
```

I found in the blob property MD5 hash of the entire file, not individual block/chunk.  I could verify this once all the blocks/chunks are downloaded, i.e.

```
if (fileHash == blob.Properties.ContentMD5){ /* download was good */ }
```

To save download time, is there a way to get the saved MD5 hash of each block/chunk so I can compare it before downloading a new block/chunk?

Thoughts?